# How to select the month within Date Of Birth section within Discord website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to have Selenium automate Discord Date of Birth

I've got this so far but can't figure out how to get it to select a random month

```
# Discord Date Of Birth
month = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#app-mount > div.app-3xd6d0 > div > div > div > form > div > div > div.container-2UAUAG.marginTop20-2T8ZJx > div.inputs-3ELGTz > div.month-1Z2bRu > div > div > div > div')
month.click()
```

Comment: Discord has an extensive API to automate virtually everything.  Why fall back to scraping?

Comment: I agree with @TimRoberts - there are also API wrappers for the disord API for basically every language. This looks like Python so check out [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Im Working On An Automated Webased Tool That Makes Discord Accounts And Im Also New To It , I've Searched Everywhere Even On Discord.py There's Nothing Specific On How To Automate Inputs For Month , Date , Year On https://discord.com/register Everything I Find Is Discord Bot Related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to select the *Month* as ***April*** within *DOB* section of [Discord](https://discord.com/register) webpage you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://discord.com/register')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'month')]//div[text()='Select']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='css-dwar6a-menu']//div[text()='April']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: Discord_DOB_Month]